# ggplot2 , ggroc changing axis ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been trying to change my axes ticks with scale_x_discrete, continuous and nobody seems to work, i either get an error or they just dont change. Also im looking for a way to "move" both of my axes so my plot could look like the provided example.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(pROC)
library(dplyr)

#some data
data(aSAH)

# store roc object 
roc.ob <- roc(outcome ~ s100b, aSAH, percent = T)

ggroc(roc.ob) + 
coord_fixed()+
geom_abline(slope = 1 ,intercept = 100) + # add identity line
theme(
panel.background = element_blank(), 
axis.title.x = element_text(size =18, face = 'bold'),
axis.title.y = element_text(size =18, face = 'bold'),
panel.border = element_rect(size = 2, fill = NA), 
axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14, face ='bold'),
axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14, face ='bold')) +
xlab('100% - Specificity') +
ylab('100% - Sensitivity')
```

I got this:

[image]

But i need to change at free will my axes so they are in probabilities (100 -> 1, 50 -> .5 etc), and my X axis is inverted so 100 -> 0, and 0 -> 100. I give an example, i know i can just change my axis title so its technically correct, but i would want to know if i can change them.  And if i could just put the ticks in every side of the plot frame that would be great :D. ¿How could i change my axes?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can definitely change your axis. It may give a warning because the `ggroc()` function already reversed the x-axis, but that is not a problem.

Most of the adjustments happen in the scales, a couple of points:

- You can change the labelling by providing a custom function to the `labels` argument, if they underlying data was in percentage space instead of probability space
- You can add a secondary axis with identity transformation `~ .x` to have tickmarks appear in the top and on the right.
- You can set expand to `c(0,0)` to not have any whitespace padding around the axes. I saw your example didn't have it, so I replicated that.
- Lastly, in the theme, you can set the axis tick lengths of the secondary axis to a negative unit, to have the ticks point inward, like the example you gave.

I've not included all your theme settings that were not necessary to demonstrate this.

```r
ggroc(roc.ob) + 
  coord_fixed()+
  geom_abline(slope = 1 ,intercept = 100) + # add identity line
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "reverse", name = "100% - Specificity",
                     labels = function(x){format(x/100)},
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ .x, labels = NULL),
                     expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "100% - Sensitivity",
                     labels = function(x){format(x/100)},
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ .x, label = NULL),
                     expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(5, "pt"),
        axis.ticks.length.x.top = unit(-5, "pt"),
        axis.ticks.length.y.right = unit(-5, "pt"),
        panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]